# Does the GUI work on Linux?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, linux

I am running Debian and the latest stable version of libstdc++6 (provided by Debian) does not include the versions necessary to run the GUI.

> CXXABI_1.3.9 and GLIBCXX_3.4.21

I spoke to a friend who is running Ubuntu and has the same problem. Does the GUI work on Linux as Debian and its fork Ubuntu are the most widely used distros?

Is there a way to get this working as I doubt users are expected to copile gcc and g++ just to run the GUI.

I already have gcc-4.9 g++-4.9.

Comment: This issue seems to vary from person to person, but this definitely needs to be addressed for those who are having these problems even if it is a smaller portion of those on linux it is working fine for. This is why we have beta releases :)

Comment: I can start the UI (start-gui.sh) without a problem on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Linux is widely used by Monero users as they understand that Apple and Windows are spyware.

Comment: could you please sum up the installation requirements? I can't start it on a basic Debian 64 installation.
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Download __monero.gui.linux.x64.beta.tar.bz2__. Extract it. Go inside the __monero-wallet-gui__ folder. Run "./start-gui.sh" with the command line.

Comment: And hope it works. @Chris it seems the stdc++ libraries in Debian stable are a lower version than the GUI and so the GUI doesn't work. Strange as alot of us use Linux around here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install curl-devel libcurl glib-devel libtool

Comment: Can you edit your answer to clarify that you are recommending the use of a specific command to help solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Linux beta binaries are built on Ubuntu 16.04. No sure which GCC version Fluffypony used but the downloadable bins on [buildserver](https://build.getmonero.org/builders/monero-core-ubuntu-amd64) are built with GCC 5.4.0. Until next release we will try to complete a fully static linux build or at least bins targeted for other distros.

Comment: I don't know why the Debian repos are so far behind. We are on 4.9.2. I tried to upgrade using the "testing" repos but they require altering half my system to install. Do you perhaps know an easier way to upgrade?